# Extract data from multiple rows into one row only (moving data from vertical view to horizontal view)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with multiple rows and columns.
Column A: list of unique identifiers (invoice number as an example)
Column B: description of type of charge that applies to that invoice, one charge per row, all using the same "invoice number"
Column C: value of those individual charges, one value per row, all using the same "invoice number"
For each columns, there are could be multiple rows using the same unique identifier number in column 1. (Row 1, 2, .... 10, not any specific number of rows)

many more columns in there too. how to move from a vertical level of all charges listed row by row using the same unique identifier number to a horizontal level, where there is only one row for each invoice number, and all those charges and values are pulled into columns instead? No macro best (no macro experience)

[image]

Comment: This can be done easily with Power Query (available in windows Excel 2010+ and O365). If you provide some sample data, and desired outcome, I may be able to help.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want for results, this can also be easily done with a simple Pivot Table: `Rows:ID`; `Columns:`Type of Charge`; `Values: Value`

Comment: @Ron, I just added a small example of data in my original comment. it is a link to a picture. column B is the list of invoice numbers. I need just one row for each invoice number. Column F (rate category), one per row, I want those to become one column for each of those rate categories, and everything that is in column G needs to fall under the appropriate column of rate name/category.

Comment: You still don't show what you expect for an outcome. Once you do, it should be easy to accomplish with either Power Query or an ordinary Pivot Table.  Oh, and I have no way of copying your screenshot into a worksheet (nor the patience to enter it manually). I suggest that to make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the =UNIQUE function:

Enter this formula into cell F2 `=IFERROR(INDEX(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$21),ROW(F2)-ROW($F$2)+1),"")`

and this formula into cell G2 `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$21,SMALL(IF($F2=$A$2:$A$21,ROW($A$2:$A$21)-ROW($A$2)+1),FLOOR.MATH((COLUMN(G1)-COLUMN($G$1))/2)+1),MOD(COLUMN(G1)-COLUMN($G$1),2)+1),"")` and use the fill handle to drag down and to the right

[image]

---

To Make the charge appear in the corresponding column, enter this formula instead to G2 and drag down and right:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$21,SMALL(IF(($F2=$A$2:$A$21)*(INDEX($G$1:$X$1,FLOOR.MATH((COLUMN(G1)-COLUMN($G$1))/2)*2+1)=$B$2:$B$21),ROW($A$2:$A$21)-ROW($A$2)+1),1),MOD(COLUMN(G1)-COLUMN($G$1),2)+1),"")`

[image]

OR,
`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$21,SMALL(IF(($F2=$A$2:$A$21)*(G$1=$B$2:$B$21),ROW($A$2:$A$21)-ROW($A$2)+1),1)),"")`
for this:
[image]

In which case, a pivot table might make more sense, but this is the formula version...

Comment: let me know if that works, or if you don't have the =UNIQUE function

Comment: Thank you Dave. Fantastic find, and yes it seems I have the UNIQUE function. The only problem I have with this is that ideally I would want all the charges named "charge 2" to be in the "charge 2" column. From what I see, this one formula does not help with organizing the charges values into fixed "charge name" columns. Let's say, for all invoices that have "charge 2" name and value, I would like the value to be shown in the "charge 2" name column

Comment: @Monica what do you mean by "fantastic find"? :)

Comment: I meant this is still great for me to use on another report. What you just showed me is still very valuable to me. For the purpose of this report though, I would need a little tweaking as described in my previous comment. I would want to create a column for each one of those specific charges names and pull the corresponding value into that column.

Comment: @Monica check updated answer.